# Question for the function $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{x^2}{x-2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Let the function defined by

$$f(x)=\log\left(\frac{x^2}{x-2}\right)$$
which of the following affirmations is **FALSE**?

$\fbox{A}\, f\,$ has an absolute minimum;

$\fbox{B}\, f(x)>0,\quad  \forall x\in\operatorname{dom} f$ ;

$\fbox{C}\, f\,$ have not inflected;

$\fbox{D}\, f\,$ restricted to $]2; 4[$ is invertible;

$\fbox{E}\, \nexists\, c\in \operatorname{dom} f \mid f(c)=0$.

---

*My attempt to resolve it.* Being the $\operatorname{dom} f=]2,+\infty[$ and the $\lim_{x\to2+}f(x)>0$, and hence $\fbox{B}$ is **true**. It is **true** the $\fbox{D}$, because if I switch $x\leftrightarrow y$, I think that I will have an exponential function of base $e$. If $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{x^2}{x-2}\right)=0 \iff \frac{x^2}{x-2}=1$ and this have not real roots. Hence it is **true** the $\fbox{E}$. For the inflected I  think that $f$ it has any so it is **true** the $\fbox{C}$. Definitively I think that the **false** is the $\fbox{A}$ (see Weiestrass's theorem: $]2,+\infty[$ is not closed and limited).

Dear users, I ask you if there are any errors and I wait your observations/answers.

Comment: It has an absolute minimum: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+log%28x%5E2%2F%28x-2%29%29

Comment: @IntegrateThis Thank you for your comment, but it is an exercise for a student which not can use the calculators or other struments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can apply the extended version of Weierstrass theorem (i.e. [Extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)) indeed since

$$\lim_{x\to 2^+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=\infty$$

$f(x)$ continuous has an absolute minimum.

The false is $C$ indeed we have

$$f''(x)=-\frac{x^2-8x+8}{x^2(x-2)^2}=0 \iff x^2-8x+8=0 \implies x=4+2\sqrt 2$$

which is an inflection point.

Comment: With all sincerity I have chosen the real C because the student I am helping is registered in a Faculty of Economics and Finance and mathematics is a hard rock because the students are not very well prepared an they not can use calculators, notes, books etc. and the time to solve the test is 90'. In fact I have not any calculus. However I will ask a question how to use the extended version of Weierstrass theorem. $\infty^n$ thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano The extended version is obtained from the base case. It suffices to set an upper value and show, using IVT, that we can find a compact subdomain on which $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @Sebastiano What does it mean "the real C"?

Comment: You ask me the impossible. Who remembers these definitions any longer? I have never studied this theorem. :( sigh sigh.

Comment: It is the use of Deepl translator: I wanted to write that I have chosen the $C$ because I not thinked to do any calculus.

Comment: @Sebastiano Of course we can choose $C$ by exclusion.

Comment: I have ask a new question for the theorem. :-)

Comment: @user Are you sure your derivative is correct?