# How to use the extended version of Weierstrass's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples, extreme-value-theorem

After my question [Question for the function $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{x^2}{x-2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806529/question-for-the-function-fx-log-left-fracx2x-2-right?noredirect=1#comment7846159_3806529), I have obtain a very good answer and I remember that I have never studied this theorem during my period at my university (1993) "*extended version of Weierstrass's theorem"*. Obviously there are several pages on the internet that discuss the proof of the theorem. I would like to understand well the hypotheses and when and how to apply the theorem in practical cases especially **for the students of an high school**.

I have seen that are used the sequences and the minimum and maximum limits ($\lim \sup$, $\lim \min$)  and I do not remember their use and the meaning of this concepts.

Comment: Thank you very much to @Eric Wofsey to edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generalization of [EVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), in its simplest version, is not a particular theorem but a
method which has the aim to extend the result, for continuous functions,  when the hypotesis for a closed domain fails to be true.

In this particular case we are dealing with a continuous function defined on an open interval $(a,b)$ and such that

$$\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)=\infty$$

Under such conditions we can extend EVT to prove that the given function must have an absolute minimum. Fixed a suitable upper limit $M$, the key point is to show by IVT that a closed interval $[c,d]\subseteq(a,b)$ exists such that

$$f(c)\le M \, \land \, f(d)\le M $$

therefore $f: [c,d]\to \mathbb R$  fullfils the hypotesis for EVT and hence an absolute minimum exists also for the original function.

Comment: Again thank you very very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano You are welcome! Bye